# Uncaught (in promise) FirebaseError: Invalid collection reference. Collection references must have an odd number of segments

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am getting the error

```
    Uncaught (in promise) FirebaseError: Invalid collection reference. Collection references must have an odd number of segments, but 
Accounts/sKnjAQzJ1sQ5qRC4ki6b/RequestsReceived/m27vTB22izq6UixWP2s6 has 4.
```

My code is

```
var ref2 = collection(db, "Accounts/" + localStorage.getItem('Id') + "/RequestsReceived", id);
    const docRef2 = await getDoc(ref2);
    await deleteDoc (ref2);
```

The document I want to delete has the URL `/Accounts/sKnjAQzJ1sQ5qRC4ki6b/RequestsReceived/m27vTB22izq6UixWP2s6`

I understand that if you add a document, it has to have an odd number of path, the collection name, or collection/document/collection. But shouldn't deleteDoc have an even amount because I'm deleting collection/document or collection/document/collection/document. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `"Accounts/" + localStorage.getItem('Id') + "/RequestsReceived", id`

This path is pointing towards a document in 'RequestsReceived' sub-collection. So you should be using `doc()` to create a DocumentReference.

Also you don't need to fetch a document before deleting as long as you have the reference:

```
// ensure all values are defined
console.log(localStorage.getItem('Id'), id);

// use doc()
var ref2 = doc(db, "Accounts/" + localStorage.getItem('Id') + "/RequestsReceived", id);

await deleteDoc(ref2);
```

Comment: Oh thank you, this is my first time with FireBase and I skipped parts of a tutorial, just realized this. Thank you.